# Python: Sorting DataFrame according to values in Second DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, sorting

I'm very new to Python and I need help because I can't come up with a solution.

**Upadate: I might need to have a third dataframe in case of a tie. Values in column 2 can only be int from 1 to 4, if that's relevant.**

I have three dataframes:

Dataframe 1:

```
      col1  col2  
0       B    1    
1       Y    2    
2       A    3 
3       A    3
4       C    4
5       C    4
```

Dataframe 2:

```
      col1  col2  
0      S     1   
1      P     2    
2      P     2
3      J     4
4      J     4
```

Dataframe 3:

```
      col1  col2  
0      N     1    
1      L     2    
2      L     2 
3      O     3
```

I need to find a way to sort each of them so that if one element in col2 in df1 is also in col2 in df2, they take the last and first position, respectively.

Now, there is also a third df. I need to also apply the logic above so the result look like this. We don't care what's in the middle as long as the first and last position of subsequent data frames match, if there are elements in common.

The desired output should be like this:

Dataframe 1:

```
      col1  col2  
0      B     1    
1      Y     2   
2      A     3
3      A     3
4      C     4
5      C     4
```

Dataframe 2:

```
      col1  col2  
0      J      4  
1      J      4   
2      S      1
3      P      2
4      P      2
```

Dataframe 3:

```
      col1  col2  
0      L      2  
1      L      2   
2      N      1
3      O      3
```

Any ideas? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "together"? `1` is in `col2` of both `df1` and `df2` but it's in row 2 of `df1` and row 0 of `df2`.

Comment: They don't have to be literally together, because they need to remain in their original data frames. By that I meant that the order must change, so for example, 1 moves to position 2 of df1 and 1 moves to position 0 of df2. That way, at least one value that is in both, df1 and df2, moves to the last and first position, respectively.

Comment: Could you give an example with a few more rows? I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: Sure! I'll add it as an update.

Answer (score 0):

So the goal is to move common values to end of `df1` and beginning of `df2`.

First, find the common values

```
common = pd.merge(df1[['col2']], df2[['col2']], on='col2', how='inner')['col2'].unique().tolist()
```

Then, sort `df1`

```
df1 = df1.sort_values('col2', ascending=True, key=lambda x: x in common)
```

Then, sort `df2`

```
df2 = df2.sort_values('col2', ascending=False, key=lambda x: x in common)
```

Comment: this returns an error when run

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: It's giving me this error: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()